# How to run white noise and autoregressive model (1) on observations

Tags: r, autoregressive-models, whitenoise

I'm trying to utilize the FitAR package and an autoregressive model/AR(1) --see #A below-- to compare noise (e.g. white/random noise, see #B below) to lynx counts. Setting this up has been confusing. I'm pulling a random noise example I came across and lynx data from FitAR. The white noise model would help determine what may be of significance in the lynx data.

#A lynx

```
install.packages(FitAR)
library(FitAR)
library(lattice)
library(leaps)
library(ltsa)
library(bestglm)
help("FitAR-package")

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
lynx <- (log(lynx))
ans <- FitAR((lynx),1)
z4<-Boot.FitAR(ans)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))

TimeSeriesPlot((lynx))
title(main="lynx")

TimeSeriesPlot(z4)
title(main="Simulated AR lynx")
```

#B white noise

```
install.packages("compositions")
library("compositions")

rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)

set.seed(100) 
x <- NULL
x[1] <- 0
for (i in 2:100) {
  x[i] <- x[i-1] + rnorm(1,0,1)
}
ts.plot(x, main = 'Random walk', xlab = '', ylab = '', col='blue', lwd = 2)
```

Comment: Where is the `N` variable coming from? It might help it include the FitAR & composition libraries in the code examples. It'll help others to run and debug the code
`
install.packages("compositions")
library("compositions")
`

Comment: Thanks Lex. The "N" is not needed actually after reviewing, made edits, and added composition libraries. Yes, trying to figure out how the white noise portion can be run on lynx data, or how lynx data can be brought into the white noise to determine significant lynx data. This could be run on red noise too I suppose. Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This book has some [examples](https://nwfsc-timeseries.github.io/atsa-labs/sec-tslab-white-noise-wn.html) generating white noise time series in R.

```
set.seed(123)
## random normal variates
GWN <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 5, sd = 0.2)
## random Poisson variates
PWN <- rpois(n = 50, lambda = 20)
TimeSeriesPlot(GWN)
TimeSeriesPlot(PWN)
```

[image]

You can use these white noise examples with FitAR.

```
ans <- FitAR(GWN, 1, MeanMLEQ=TRUE)
TimeSeriesPlot(ans)
```

[image]

This FitAR [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FitAR/FitAR.pdf) I found interesting

It has an example simulating Gaussian noise

```
library(FitAR)
set.seed(123)
phi <- c(2.7607, -3.8106, 2.6535, -0.9238)
z <- SimulateGaussianAR(phi, 1000)
ans <- FitAR(z, 4, MeanMLEQ=TRUE)
TimeSeriesPlot(ans)
```

Comment: Thanks Lex, for sharing the links. Reviewing this.

Comment: Need to estimate AR (1) parameter from the lynx data, then run simulations of the white noise. Need to figure out "how to pair/nest/link" the AR (1) output and white noise model together, then plot both lynx data and white noise data with confidence intervals. Any insights appreciated.